# Assistance with starting off with the Gmail API

Tags: c#, google-api, gmail-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I need help on how to start off with google apis and how to make my first functioning gmail app (in c#)

Answer (score 0):

Google has a sample for use with .net and gmail [Quick start .net](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/dotnet) its a good place to start.  This sample is designed however for installed applications.

```
credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                        GoogleClientSecrets.FromStream(stream).Secrets,
                        Scopes,
                        "user",
                        CancellationToken.None,
                        new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
                    Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
```

If your working iwht a web app then you will need to follow the authorizatonm from this [sample](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-asp.net-core-3).  As there is a web auth and installed auth are diffrent

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...

    // This configures Google.Apis.Auth.AspNetCore3 for use in this app.
    services
        .AddAuthentication(o =>
        {
            // This forces challenge results to be handled by Google OpenID Handler, so there's no
            // need to add an AccountController that emits challenges for Login.
            o.DefaultChallengeScheme = GoogleOpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            // This forces forbid results to be handled by Google OpenID Handler, which checks if
            // extra scopes are required and does automatic incremental auth.
            o.DefaultForbidScheme = GoogleOpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            // Default scheme that will handle everything else.
            // Once a user is authenticated, the OAuth2 token info is stored in cookies.
            o.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddCookie()
        .AddGoogleOpenIdConnect(options =>
        {
            options.ClientId = {YOUR_CLIENT_ID};
            options.ClientSecret = {YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET};
        });
}
```

Comment: let me know if you have any issues

Comment: @DalmTo This sounds really stupid, but how do you get the credentials.json file ?

Comment: I have a video on how to create the json file so this is not stupid a stupid question https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pBVAyU4pZOU just remember to enable the gmail api under libraries